# MySQL sub_string search (prefix ID's)

Tags: mysql

I have location ID's with two letter location prefix followed by a number

> (AB1, AB2. CA1, CA2, CD1)

that will sequentially increment by 1 each time a new record is added against a given location. To find the last added ID matching the prefix I'm using a mysql substring .. Its something like this ...

```
SELECT MAX( SUBSTRING( `locationID` , 3, 11 ) )
FROM `items`
WHERE LEFT( `locationID` , 2 ) = "AL"
```

It doesn't work (it would only pick up numbers under 10) Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it to number:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING( locationID , 3, 11 ) AS UNSIGNED))
```

Comment: when I try converting this into CodeIgniter MCV it doesnt work.. this is what I have ... function getMaxIDMatchingPrefix($locationPrefix){
  $sql = "SELECT MAX( SUBSTRING( `locationID` , 3, 11 ) )
  FROM `items`
  WHERE LEFT( `locationID` , 2 ) =  = ? ";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, $locationPrefix);
  return $query;
 }

Comment: @pks: Ask another question then, I don't know how CI query generator works.